# Error when mapping a DynamoDB table with Hive on Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, amazon-dynamodb

It's been almost two hours I'm struggling with a DynamoDB table through Hive on Spark.
I can properly retrieve the table from Hive directly, but I need to get it from Hive on Spark now.
The error is :

```
pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException: u"\nOperation not allowed: STORED BY
```

I think I have properly injected the JARS plugin, I have put it in the jars arg and also tried spark.driver.extraClassPath & spark.executor.extraClassPath in spark-defaults.conf

My code :

```
sqlContext.sql("CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE dynTable (idPlace string) STORED BY 
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler' TBLPROPERTIES 
('dynamodb.table.name' = 'MYTABLE',  'dynamodb.column.mapping' = 'idPlace:idPlace')")
```

Do you have any idea ?

I'm using EMR 5.5 with PySpark

Thanks :)